# como hago para que el programa no me cierre cuando no cumple la condicion?

Tags: java, condiciones, while, switch

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
               int opcion;
               do{
                           opcion=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese una opcion \n1.evaluar contraseña"
                                   + "\n2.salir"));
                           
                           switch(opcion){
                               case 1:String psw  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese contraseña:");
                                CheckPsw evalue = new CheckPsw();
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, evalue.check(psw));
                                while(evalue.check(psw) == "secuencia no valida"||evalue.check(psw) == "rango no disponible"){
                                    psw  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese contraseña:");
                                    evalue = new CheckPsw();
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, evalue.check(psw));
                           }break;            
                                
                               case 2:JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"proceso finalizado");
                               System.exit(0);
                               break;
                               default:
                               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Opcion Incorrecta");
                           
                           }
           }while(opcion!=2||opcion!=1);
        }
```

este programa, basicamente lee una contraseña, y si no cumple con los requisitos, me la debe volver a pedir, si evalue.check(psw)=="secuencia no valida" o "rango no disponible", entonces deberia volverme a pedir la contraseña(aqui esta el fragmento de codigo especifico por si les interesa):

```
 while(evalue.check(psw) == "secuencia no valida"||evalue.check(psw) == "rango no disponible"){
                                    psw  = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese contraseña:");
                                    evalue = new CheckPsw();
                                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, evalue.check(psw));
                           }break;
```

Comment: evalue.check() retorna un string, podrìas agregar este mètodo por favor? Que error obtienes cuando se cierra tu app?

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente es importante saber que la comparaciòn de cadenas en java se realiza usando el mètodo `.equals()`, por lo tanto el còdigo deberìa ser:

```
//while(evalue.check(psw) == "secuencia no valida"||evalue.check(psw) == "rango no disponible"){
while(evalue.check(psw) == "secuencia no valida"||evalue.check(psw) == "rango no disponible"){
```

Answer (score 0):

bastaria con evaluar si psw es diferente a "contraseña valida" y agregar un do while extra en el case 1 donde se evalua la contraseña

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int opcion;
    String temp;
    do{
    opcion = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese una opcion \n1.evaluar contraseña"
            + "\n2.salir"));

    switch(opcion) {
        case 1:
            do {
                String psw = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese contraseña:");
                CheckPsw value = new CheckPsw();
                temp = value.check(psw);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, temp);
            }while(!"Contraseña valida".equals(temp));
         break;
        case 2:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"proceso finalizado");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Opcion Incorrecta");    
    }
    }while(opcion!=2||opcion!=1);
}
```